# Cannonjs collision handling

Tags: three.js, cannon.js

I have two cannonjs boxes. Box1 serve as character that moves with arrow keys.Box 2 serve as house . When i move Box1 towards Box2 , Box1 gets sliding to very large distance continuously.  I want that when the two boxes collide nothing happen . Both stay at their places.

I have used various friction and restitution values but nothing help me